# MySQL Totals by data in table

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, pivot, calculated-columns

A friend runs a daily fantasy sports type pool using golf major tournaments every year. It's been handled as an excel spreadsheet and now he's asking for help converting it to a website using PHP and MySQL in WordPress.

There are two tables:

Golfers (condensed):

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
|  gName  | Rd1 | Rd2 | Rd3 | Rd4 | SRd1 | SRd2 | SRd3 | SRd4 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
| Spieth  |  71 |  70 |  68 |  71 |    0 |    1 |    3 |    0 |
| Johnson |  70 |  70 |  69 |  70 |    1 |    1 |    2 |    1 |
| Day     |  71 |  71 |  70 |  71 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Where golfers earn pool participants "points" for each stroke under Par (SRd1...)

and Players (condensed) where their 'roster' by tournament is stored:

```
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|  pName  |  gName  | SRd1 | SRd2 | SRd3 | SRd4 | Total |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Player1 | Spieth  |    0 |    1 |    3 |    0 |     4 |
| Player1 | Johnson |    1 |    1 |    2 |    1 |     5 |
| Player1 | Day     |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |     1 |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

I use a single query to scrape the relevant data I need and input it into both tables, Golfers and Players.

I have no problem displaying a table with the leaderboard of just the golfers, that's a straight forward SELECT query

My friend wants to display results by pool participant similar to this:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Player1 | SRd1 | SRd2 | SRd3 | SRd4 | Total |
+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Spieth  |    0 |    1 |    3 |    0 |     4 |
| Johnson |    1 |    1 |    2 |    1 |     5 |
| Day     |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |     1 |
| Total   |    1 |    2 |    6 |    1 |    10 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

My current query is:

```
<table>
<?php
global $wpdb;

$golfers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mr2017");

foreach ($golfers as $golfer ) {
    if ($golfer->pName != $lastp){
        echo '<tr height=10></tr>';
            echo '<tr>
            <th>' . $golfer->pName . '</th>
            <th> Rd1 </th>
            <th> Rd2 </th>
            <th> Rd3 </th>
            <th> Rd4 </th>
            <th>Total</th>
            </tr>';
            $lastp = $golfer->pName;
        }
        echo '<tr>
            <td>' .$golfer->mName. '</td>
            <td>' .$golfer->SRd1. '</td>
            <td>' .$golfer->SRd2. '</td>
            <td>' .$golfer->SRd3. '</td>
            <td>' .$golfer->SRd4. '</td>
            <td>' .$golfer->Tot. '</td>
            </tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Questions:

1. What is the best way to handle the 'Total' row? By including a
   'Total' as a 'gName' in the Players table and including the total by
   column in that? Or is there a way to use a SUM in my query?
2. What is the best way to maintain the golfer scores? Currently I
   update their scores in each table using a single scraping query. Is
   it better to SELECT these results from a join query?

Hopefully this is clear enough, I'm not a programmer at all, just trying to learn it for myself.

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain and normalise your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet (or a golf scorecard)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for this? If I knew what that was or how to do that I would have...

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get you started, an example of a normalised environment might be as follows (it might be worth mentioning at this point that I know next to nothing about golf).

```
golfers
+------------+---------+
|  golfer_id | name    |
+------------+---------+
|          1 | Spieth  |
|          2 | Johnson |
|          3 | Day     |
+------------+---------+

par
+-----+
| par |
+-----+
|  71 |
+-----+

scorecard
+-----------+-------+-------+
| golfer_id | round | score |
+-----------+-------+-------+
|         1 |     1 |    71 |
|         1 |     2 |    70 |
|         1 |     3 |    68 |
|         1 |     4 |    71 |
...
+-----------+-------+-------+
```

You may need to explain a bit more about the relationship between 'tournaments' and 'rounds'

Comment: There are 4 tournaments that get tracked over the season. Within the tournament there are 4 rounds of golf. In the example I mentioned earlier, If Par is 71, every stroke under Par  is 1 point. If a golfer scores 70 on their Thursday round in tournament 1, that is worth 1 point in that round.  

I think I see where you're going with the breakout of the tables, I have no idea what should be broken out or how to join them.

I'm in finance, spreadsheets make sense to me which is why I've structured it that way.

Comment: Normalisation is fundamental to relational database design. Just give it some time to sink in

Comment: I can see using a JOIN query to reference my 'Golfers' table, but to artificially break that apart, when the data is stored in the format it will be displayed on a page and risk making an error on my SELECT statement doesn't make any sense to me. I can essentially pull that table as-is without worrying about multiple JOIN statements I'm not even sure how to do.

Comment: We have different perceptions of time. It's inevitable, I guess.

Comment: In the example you provided, wouldn't I essentially be pivoting the data in the 'scorecard' table to get it to display properly?

Comment: Yes. But you'd typically handle the 'pivot' in your application code (php or some wp plugin).